# Django shell mode in docker

Tags: python, django, shell, docker, docker-compose

I am learning how to develop Django application in docker with this official tutorial: https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/

I have successfully run through the tutorial, and

`docker-compose run web django-admin.py startproject composeexample .` creates the image
`docker-compose up` runs the application

The question is:

I often use `python manage.py shell` to run Django in shell mode, but I do not know how to achieve that with docker.

Comment: Try `docker exec -ti your_container /bin/bash` to get a shell inside the running container. You can then run any management command.

Comment: By shell mode, I actually mean the interactive mode. My fault for confusing wording

Comment: Yes, it can be confusing. My command gives you a bash shell inside the container. From that shell you can run your `python manage.py shell` to get the Django Python shell, or other commands that should be run inside the container.

Answer (score 34):

I use this command (when run with compose)

```
docker-compose run <service_name> python manage.py shell
```

where `<service name>` is the name of the docker service(in docker-compose.yml).

So, In your case the command will be

```
docker-compose run web python manage.py shell
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/

When run with Dockerfile

```
docker exec -it <container_id> python manage.py shell
```

Answer (score 13):

1. Run `docker exec -it --user desired_user your_container bash` 
   Running this command has similar effect then runing `ssh` to remote server - after you run this command you will be inside container's bash terminal. You will be able to run all Django's manage.py commands.
2. Inside your container just run `python manage.py shell`

Answer (score 4):

If you're using `docker-compose` you shouldn't always `run` additional containers when it's not needed to, as **each run will start new container and you'll lose a lot of disk space**. So you can end up with running multiple containers when you totally won't have to. Basically it's better to:

1. Start your services once with `docker-compose up -d`
2. Execute (instead of running) your commands:

```
docker-compose exec web ./manage.py shell
```

or, if you don't want to start all services (because, for example - you want to run only one command in Django), then you should pass `--rm` flag to `docker-compose run` command, so the container will be removed just after passed command will be finished.

```
docker-compose run --rm web ./manage.py shell
```

In this case when you'll escape shell, the container created with `run` command will be destroyed, so you'll save much space on your disk.

Answer (score 3):

You can use docker exec in the container to run commands like below.

```
docker exec -it container_id python manage.py shell
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Docker Compose (using command `docker compose up`) to spin up your applications, after you run that command then you can run the interactive shell in the container by using the following command:

```
docker compose exec <container id or name of your Django app> python3 <path to your manage.py file, for example, src/manage.py> shell
```

Keep in mind the above is using Python version 3+ with `python3`.